# Using ADB2C phone factor technical profile to validate a phone number before creating an account

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to create a custom ADB2C policy which should follow a journey such as...

1. User enters a phone number to verify
2. User receives a code to verify the number and enters this on the view
3. A claim is set which is used in the next step to save to AD.

I can see I need to use the phone factor technical profile as per the Microsoft docs, but I couldn't see whether this could be done before a user has signed up as it seems to want a UserID as an input claim (see [Input claims required](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/phone-factor-technical-profile#input-claims)). All the samples seem to point to MFA and editing phones already associated to a user.

Is it possible to do this?

Secondly, is there any value in mixing the one-time password technical profile in this flow or is that more for just OTP code generation (not sending and accepting the inputs from the user)?

### Update

So Ive managed to create the user journey which shows the UI correctly so it seems I can enter a phone number but now when I submit it I get an error "AADB2C90154: A multi-factor verification request failed to get a session id from the service."

As far as I can tell, the session technical profile is fine so not sure what the problem could be?

I also tried disabling the session but its seems like the phone tech profile needs it?

### Sample technical profile

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify">
                <DisplayName>PhoneFactor</DisplayName>
                <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.PhoneFactorProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
                <Metadata>
                    <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.phonefactor</Item>
                    <Item Key="ManualPhoneNumberEntryAllowed">true</Item>
                    <Item Key="setting.authenticationMode">sms</Item>
                    <Item Key="setting.autodial">true</Item>
                </Metadata>
                <CryptographicKeys>
                    <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
                </CryptographicKeys>
                <InputClaims>
                    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userIdForMFA" PartnerClaimType="UserId" DefaultValue="TEST" />
                    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="phoneNumber" />
                </InputClaims>
                <OutputClaims>
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="verifiedPhone" PartnerClaimType="Verified.OfficePhone" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newVerifiedPhone" PartnerClaimType="newPhoneNumberEntered" />
                </OutputClaims>
            </TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: Also, is there any info on the charges for actually sending the SMS/call? I couldn't see any mention of this on the Azure site?

Comment: Pricing can be found here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory-b2c/ it indicates that MFA and SMS events are $0.03 / event.

Comment: In regards to your custom flow. Are you wanting the user to only signup with a phone number?

Comment: No, the signup will be with email and pw, but we have a requirement to have a confirmed phone number so using the "sign in with phone number" policy is not the route we need (for now)

Comment: Okay. So does the MFA setup occur before or after the user enters their email address?

Comment: Beforehand. So basically before we get to the email/pw orchestration step

Comment: Also when I do get the phone entry screen up and enter a value, I get the error AADB2C90154: A multi-factor verification request failed to get a session id from the service.

I just used the Session management code in the starter pack but it doesnt seem to like it?

Comment: can you update your post with the technical profile for the MFA?

Comment: @ChristopherNorris See above now. I am just calling this in a ClaimsExchange in step 1 and then outputting the claims in a JWT in step 2.

Comment: Raj, can  you confirm MFA is enabled https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-multi-factor-authentication

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213791/discussion-between-christopher-norris-and-raj).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Raj,

I don't see how you are setting the userIdForMFA other than the default value? However, the Azure documentation isn't very clear here. Try using an inputClaimsTransformation that sets the userId Value.

For example: 
Add this to the MFA technical profile:

```
      <InputClaimsTransformations>
        <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserIdForMFA2" />
      </InputClaimsTransformations>
```

Add this to your claims transformation:

```
  <ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateUserIdForMFA2" TransformationMethod="CreateStringClaim">
    <InputParameters>
      <InputParameter Id="value" DataType="string" Value="test12345@{YourTenant}.onmicrosoft.com"/>
    </InputParameters>
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userIdForMFA" TransformationClaimType="createdClaim" />
    </OutputClaims>
  </ClaimsTransformation>
```

Comment: Perfect. Seems like the default value just never gets applied and it has to be in the format of an 'email address'. Gotta love the docs!

Comment: Just opened an issue with B2C https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/54786